# Custom Dictionary in MS Office

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016, dictionary

With Coral Office (WordPerfect) I simply store the Custom Dictionary in Dropbox. Word corrections can then follow me on all devices that I use.

How do I do this with MS Office?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create custom dictionaries in MS Word.

Click File > Options > Proofing (In the new dialog box) and click Custom dictionaries button. Then click New and choose the location to save the dictionary and choose name. Now click Save.

Now it's time to add entries. Click File > Options > Proofing (In the new dialog box) and click Custom dictionaries button. Check the custom dictionary and click Edit Word List.
Now add words to the dictionary and click Add. Now click OK once done.

You can check dictionaries to use from Custom dictionaries dialog box.

Hope that helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.